# Distribution Function Symbol Problem

Tags: probability, density-function

i am doing my exercises about distribution and this is the density function.
tho i have never seen in my lecture the $\mathbf{1}_{[a, b]}(t)$ symbol and i have no one to ask about it. i dont understand what it means and so i cant start any kind of calculation.

$f_{X}(t)=\frac{1}{b-a} \mathbf{1}_{[a, b]}(t)$

can anyone help me with the meaning of it?

Comment: see [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

Comment: A bold $1$ with a set [call it $A$] as subscript means the function which is $1$ if the input is in $A$ and is $0$ otherwise. So in your example the function is $1$ if $a \le x \le b$ and $0$ otherwise.